# Django Unknown Fields()

Tags: python, django

I have my code running on another machine and it's working perfectly, it's exactly the same code since I'm using github for version control, but when I run on my machine I started to get this error, I use postgres, I already tried give drop in the database and create another but continue with this error.
The error started after I imported the database from the machine that is running fine.
When I tried to go back to the local database, I started to have an error, I already tried to reinstall all the packages (those installed via pip) and nothing.

I'm using Django 1.10

```
 Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x7f7aa3e35ef0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/documentos/pycharm/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 589, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/importlib       /__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)


  File "/home/marco/miniconda2/envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 252, in __new__
raise FieldError(message) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (country, name, instituicao) specified for User
```

Comment: maybe it is related with migrations

Comment: Delete all your migrations and recreate them by command. It is just a suggestion.

Comment: do NOT delete your migrations!!! This is the stupidest thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I managed to solve, I inadvertently commented on the line `"AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'` in my settings.py and the settings of the other machine is different from my location, it worked!